# Design and develop a single page ASP.NET web application that converts a given number

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I keep getting the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'. I'm using C# for an ASP.web application

```
public string binTodec(int num)
        {
            int binaryNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int decimalValue = 0; 
            int base1 = 1;


            while (binaryNumber > 0)
            {
                int reminder = binaryNumber % 10;
                binaryNumber = binaryNumber / 10;
                decimalValue += reminder * base1;
                base1 = base1 * 2;
            }
            Console.Write($"Decimal Value : {decimalValue} ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return decimalValue;


        }
```

Any idea what my issue is??

Comment: `int decimalValue` is clearly an integer in spite of the name, but the method is: `string binTodec()` which will come to no good when you `return decimalValue;`.  You cannot return an integer from a string method.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:asp.net-web-api] when you have `Console.ReadLine` and `Console.ReadKey` calls?

Comment: @madreflection it looks like they were just looking to test in a console app before integrating it into the web app.

Comment: @acornTime: All the more reason that the tag isn't needed. It's not specific to that technology. The minimal reproducible example reduces the problem to its core, which has nothing to do with web APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an algorithm that should work for your purposes:

```
public string binToDec(string bin)
{
    int result = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    for (int i = bin.Length - 1; i > -1; i--, exp++)
    {
        double baseVal = 2 * double.Parse((bin.Substring(i, 1)));
        if (baseVal == 0) continue;
        double expVal = (double)(exp);
        result += (int)(Math.Pow(baseVal, expVal));
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```